# React setState doesn't update immediately

Tags: reactjs

i want to render data from api, every time user writes some city in input it must change api's city section and must render new data but on submit it doesn't render, its only working after second submit

```html
  async componentDidUpdate(prevprops) {
    if (this.props.city != prevprops.city) {
      const url = `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=8246dc795dd340d98f7225813210706&q=${prevprops.city}&days=10`;
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();
      this.setState({ data: data, forecast: data.forecast.forecastday });
    }
  }
```

and if user enters just blank input its crashing

Comment: `${prevprops.city}` Did you mean to do `${this.props.city}` perhaps?

Comment: no, its componentDidUpdate i want to render every time props will change so prevprops is changed props

Comment: It seems you've a bug, I think you should use the current props value.

Comment: oops... that was the problem, thank you very much

Comment: but there is problem anyway, if i input some wrong cityname or just press enter without any data it returns error

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a Network Error issue, it's because you are making an `http` request in an https app.

You would also get an error if you make a network request for empty string and wrong city. This is because, as you know the data is wrong. In this case catch the error and throw any toast message in the App so that user can correct there error.
Instead of adding `await` multiple time, combine them

```
  await fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        console.log("data", data);
        this.setState({
        data: data,
        forecast: data.forecast.forecastday,
        error: false
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
      this.setState({ error: true });
    });
```

Here I have added, a new state called error so if there is any kind of error we throw some working message to the user.
I have sample codesandbox, for you to look into here https://codesandbox.io/embed/thirsty-bash-jqx1i?file=/src/App.js